# how to create dll accepting parameters

Tags: c++, c, dll

I have to create dll which will accept arguments and then call a exe with those parameters.

some code is as below

```
// exportimage.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>     
#include <stdlib.h>


#ifdef _MANAGED
#pragma managed(push, off)
#endif

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{

  int retCode = system("C:\\Inetpub\\wwwroot\\exporter\\res\\applet\\phantomjs.exe"
    " C:\\Inetpub\\wwwroot\\exporter\\res\\include\\highcharts-convert.js -infile"
    " C:\\Inetpub\\wwwroot\\exporter\\res\\graphs\\SVGData_137240462725.svg -outfile"
    " C:\\Inetpub\\wwwroot\\exporter\\res\\graphs\\Image_Export_137240462725.png"
    " -scale 2.5 -width 1088");
  return TRUE;
}

#ifdef _MANAGED
#pragma managed(pop)
#endif
```

Now in this I want to fetch following arguments
1) path to the exporter
2)name of .svgfile
3) name of .png file

I will pass these arguments by a html form by setting action to this dll.So please tell me what changes this will require
For the above code when I use it for the given SVG file it works but my browser gets hang so please also tell me what wrong with this like return another this etc.

I create this c++ file by vc++ and I am very new to c++.

Answer (score 1):

Put the actual code in an exported function, rather than in DllMain(). You can give that exported function any prototype you want.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but could you please give some exact code such that I will submit the form and dll function which contain code to execute exe will call

Comment: @user571616 With all due respect, StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Please try doing it yourself, and then if you get stuck ask a _specific_ question.

Answer (score 1):

You must craete entry point.

```
__declspec(dllexport)
void foo(const char* path, const char* svgfile, const char* pngfile) {
  // do something
}
```

You must not add such a code in DllMain.

Comment: but how this function foo will call when I submit the html form. Should I remove DllMain or any thing else

Comment: In this case, you don't need to add DllMain. DllMain is reserved for especially part. So you must create your function entry point.

Comment: BTW what do you mean `html form` ? Where do you want to use this dll?

Comment: I will call this dll by submitting a Html form.

Comment: Do you mean CGI or IIS ISAPI?

Comment: I will submit html form from the javascript function. I am using this on IIS server

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32557/discussion-between-user571616-and-mattn)

Comment: Sorry, currently, I can't use chat because I'm in firewall.

Comment: If you want to use dll in IIS, you must create ISAPI dll.

Comment: I am a java developer, and new to c++, just know some basics of c. Could you please tell me how to create this ISAPi dll or any link for this

Comment: The way is not just only one. Probably, you can get more easily with using ASP.NET